# How to show that ellipse has Jordan content 0?

Tags: real-analysis

For positive numbers $a,b$ show that $$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\right\}$$ has Jordan content 0. What is the strategy for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of the proof of a more general fact:

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Let $A=\{(x, f(x)):x \in[a, b]\}.$ Then, $mJ(A) = 0.$

For convenience, assume $a=0,b=1$.

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ so if $\epsilon > 0,$ there is a  $\delta > 0$ such that $|x − y| < \delta\Rightarrow  |f(x) − f(y)| <\epsilon.$

Now take $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $N \delta>1.$ Partition $[0,1]$ using uniform step sizes $h=1/N.$ Then, $\max\{f(x):x\in [x_i-x_{i-1}]\}-\min\{f(x):x\in [x_i-x_{i-1}]\}<\epsilon.$

Now, define $Q_i=[x_{i−1}, x_i]\times [\min\{f(x):x\in [x_i-x_{i-1}]\},\max\{f(x):x\in [x_i-x_{i-1}]\}]$. Then, $A\subseteq \bigcup^N_{i=1}Q_i$ and so

$mJ(Q_i)<\frac{\epsilon}{N}\Rightarrow mJ(A)\le \sum^N_{i=1} mJ(Q_i)=N\frac{\epsilon}{N}=\epsilon$, and we are done.

Now to prove your claim, apply this result to the upper and lower halves of the ellipse